# Cannot update user profile with update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For the life of me I have no idea what is going on. I am using Rails 5 with React. I cant seem to update my profile.

**Update Route:**

```
/users/:user_id/profile(.:format)   profiles#update
```

**In my react component, the form is:**

```
<form data-abide="" encType="multipart/form-data" action={url} method="patch">
  <input type="text" name="profile[first_name]" value={this.state.firstName}/>
  <button className="button expanded" type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

If I set the form method to "post", it goes to the `create` method and replace the columns which I do not need that so I changed it to `patch`.

**Profile controller:**

```
...
skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token # The only way to get this to work with React


def create
  @profile = current_user.build_profile(profile_params)
  if @profile.save
   #...
  else
   #...
  end
end

def update
  @profile = current_user.profile
  if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
    #...
  else
    #...
  end
end

private
 def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name)
 end

...
```

Is there something wrong?

**Edit:**

I get it to work, I set the form method to `post` then:

```
def create
  update
end
```

Is there a way to get the form to call the `update` method directly? As in comments, forms only supports GET/POST and not PATCH.

Comment: What do you mean by *cannot update*. Does your code raise an error? What error and where?

Comment: @spickermann Hi. No error. Not even in the console. Update as in to update the fields. Say I want to change my first name, it wont change.

Comment: What do the logs say? Is the action called? Is the SQL executed (and rolled back?) Have you tried to call the controller from a pure HTML form or CURL?

Comment: What does the HTML look like? What does React do with method="patch"? Are you sure this works as expected? Usually there is a hidden field which fakes the methods because forms only support GET/POST.

Comment: @pascalbetz Thats the issue, I never knew forms only supports GET/POST. What I did was to call the update method in the create method. But how to call the update method with a js form? I works but it's like: `def create update end` then set the form to `post`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the form method *POST*, add a hidden field to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />
```

This is how Rails does it when you use the form helpers (see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) and will override the method actually used to submit the form.

Comment: Dude! Sweet! I never knew that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you defined profiles as resources in routes file, you would be able to access this resource from form.

In *profiles/edit.html.erb*:

```
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %> # Additionally can add method: :patch
# your fields
<% end %>
```

In controller

```
def edit
    @profile = current_user.profile
end

def update
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
  if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
    flash[:notice] = "Your profile has been saved!"
    render some page
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Your profile has not been saved!"
    render or redirect some page
  end
end
```

In my opinion, you should check if your profile is updating correctly. Use

```
 @profile.errors
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but please read my post. I'm using react for my form, not `erb`.

Comment: @Sylar, oh sorry. You should check if your form is requesting update action and the profile is updating properly. You can also try to do update_attributes with console.